# How can I test an unsigned number?

Tags: easy68k

I'm using I/O Trap #4 to read in a number. This gives me a number, however it does not mention if it is read in as signed or unsigned. I would assume this is because it just reads it in as is and it could be either.

How can I check if my value is unsigned? i.e: How can I ensure it was between 0 and 2^32 inclusive?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to "check" this in code; the signedness of a number is not a property that is stored in the register. You have to know how to *interpret* the bits, i.e. which instructions to use when processing the number since different instructions treat the bits in different ways.

The documentation seems to be ... lacking regarding this. I would recommend simply testing it, what happens if you input `-1`? You should get `0xffffffff` in the register.